# Publish custom library jar file in local repository

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a library which is generated externally.
I am using it inside my project and all subprojects.
The problem is, the lib is for internal use only.
Is there a way to export this jar library to mavenLocal() so that in any subproject I would be able to write (or similar)

```
dependencies {
    compile('something:something:somenumber')
}
```

so the subproject will get the lib?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jar to the your local maven repository using the [mvn install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) command.  As an alternative you can tell gradle to depend on a file using [file dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub%3afile_dependencies).

A file compilation file dependency would look something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("path/to/file.jar") 
}
```